# Can I do this - if(token[0].equals(("MOVE")|("NOT")|("AND"))

Tags: java, equals

I want to make an if condition as following:

```
if(token[0].equals(("MOVE")|("NOT")|("AND"))
{

}
```

Orelse is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried compiling this?

Comment: In addition, you are using a bitwise OR operator which means nothing on your code

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, no.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

It only compares to one object at a time.

Answer (score 2):

You would write that as a bunch of independent statements all OR-red together:

```
if (token[0].equals("MOVE") || token[0].equals("NOT") || token[0].equals("AND")) {
     ...
}
```

Alternatively, using the new Java string-based switch statement:

```
switch(token[0]) {
case "MOVE":
case "NOT":
case "AND":
    ...
    break;
default:
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Heh, no. Java's not that powerful. You need to do three comparisons:

```
if(token[0].equals("MOVE") || token[0].equals("NOT") || token[0].equals("AND"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answers are correct of course, but I'll throw one more alternative out there.

```
if (token[0].matches("MOVE|NOT|AND")) {
    ...
}
```

It's a little inefficient and a classic overuse of regular expressions, but it's concise and close in spirit to what you were writing.

Answer (score 0):

A Set would do what you want.

```
    String[] commands={"MOVE", "NOT", "AND"};
    Set<String> cmds=new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(commands));
    if (cmds.contains(token[0])) {
        . . .
    }
```